# GitHub pages deployed with react-gh-pages updated the gh-pages branch but the app is showing 404

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, github-pages

I have a website hosted with GitHub Pages at `https://[username].github.io`.

I have a separate deployment for the repo `[username].github.io` and the web page hosted at `https://[username].github.io` is working fine.

I recently created a react app using create-react-app and wanted to host that to Github pages. The repo name is `react-gsap`. Now I followed the https://github.com/gitname/react-gh-pages tutorial to deploy the app to Github pages. Once I ran `npm run deploy` I see that the `gh-pages` branch is created and it has the index.html and other files that are required to run the web app.

The problem is when I access https://[username].github.io/react-gsap I am getting 404.

Here's the repo that I created: https://github.com/atiqorin/react-gsap

What am I missing?

**UPDATE**:
It was just a delay. The github pages is working now. I guess it takes some time to have the page ready. Anyone having similar issue might want to wait an hour to see the changes.

Comment: Open `gh-pages` branch and see what you got

Comment: `gh-pages` branch has the index.html and all other assets. I was able to run the app from that branch using a local http server

Comment: Did you change the settings here? https://github.com/[username]/[projectname]/settings/pages